# formencode conditional validation

Tags: python, validation, formencode

how do i validate a field conditionally based on the presence of another field.  for example, only make "state" required only if "country" is "US".

thanks,
steve

**EDIT:**

so i figured to do this:

```
chained_validators = [validators.RequireIfPresent('state', present="country")]
```

but the error message is associated with "_the_form" instead of "state".  is there a way to link it to the field instead?

Comment: Can we get a code sample, so we have more context?

Comment: I am only using the default validators, in my case "NotEmpty".  So in my example, I have two form fields, State and Country, and I only want State to be NotEmpty when Country is US.  Otherwise, State could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem during a project in my company. We wrote our own Formencode validator for this. We currently try to merge it with the main project. In the meantime you can download it here: https://github.com/GevatterGaul/formencode

There is also a Howto in, well, german: http://techblog.auf-nach-mallorca.info/2014/08/19/dynamische_formulare_validieren_mit_formencode/

But let me give you a quick rundown in the context of your example:

```
from formencode import validators
v = validators.RequireIfMatching('country', expected_value='US', required_fields=['state'])
v.to_python(dict(country='US', state='Virginia'))
```

The main benefit is, that in comparison to `validators.RequireIfPresent`, `validators.RequireIfMatching` only requires a field when a given field matches a given value. In your example, only if 'country' is 'US', then it requires the 'state' field.

Hope I could help.

Comment: there's gotta be better validation libraries out there. im using this cause of work but having an option like `not_empty` is already the start of a red flag in my book.